# CURL not giving me any response

Tags: php, curl

I am making a RESTFUL API call using PHP CURL. This is my function

```
$datastr = '{"Params": { "Dawar Khan": "", "Email": "ali.zia.1991@gmail.com", "MobileNumber": "36566339", "UserType": "G0", "IDNumber": "881041106", "IDExpiry": "03/01/2022", "DOB": "03/03/1988" }, "AccountID": "SHIP2YOUTST", "SecureHash": "53019EB8CA831A8D170C016A6550033A5B74D1B1A45F832560300756A02DB3F9"}';
$url = 'https://myurl.com';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datastr);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json_result = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($json_result);
```

**EDIT**

Adding var_dump to result gave me this.

> string(2738) "
>
> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details.

How can I know that my string is posted to the url and response has come? The $datastr has to be in string or json? Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Do $result = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($result); and tell me if you have anything

Comment: @Eric I get this. string(2738) "

Request Error

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details.

Comment: Add the curl response to your question please. (the var_dump)

Comment: @Ibu updated the question

Comment: @AliZia, you need to add a json header as your server expects the data in XML or JSON. See Felippe's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($datastr))
);
```

From your response:

> The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.

The response you are getting is stating that the API you use expects *XML* or *JSON*. Setting the content type to one or the other should solve the problem.

Comment: It works. Thanks allot. But can I get a little explanation mate?

Comment: That will tell the other site that your content type is a JSON, not HTML or mp3 file, and then parse correctly. That's how HTTP protocol works, and how your endpoint implements the REST API. I didn't know that much, you are going to do some research here.

Comment: @Ibu nice observations